# Why annotating a lambda type doesn't require -XScopedTypeVariables?

Tags: haskell

This requires `-XScopedTypeVariables`

```
handle(\(_::SomeException) -> return Nothing)
```

but this doesn't

```
handle((\_ -> return Nothing)::SomeException -> IO (Maybe Integer))
```

If `::` is allowed to annotated types inside function body, why does it require a pragma to annotate a local variable?

Comment: `_` is a variable (argument) the entire expression (the `handle` argument) is not. You can set type signature to a expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More generally than that: standard Haskell doesn't allow signatures *in patterns*, but does allow any *expression* to be given a signature. The following are all valid:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   x <- readLn
   print $ 5 + x

main' = (\y -> do {
   x <- readLn;
   print $ y + x } ) :: Int -> IO ()

main'' y = do
   x <- readLn :: IO Int
   print $ y + x :: IO ()
```

but none of these are

```
main''' = do
   (x :: Int) <- readLn
   print $ 5 + x

main''' = (\(y :: Int) -> do {
   x <- readLn;
   print $ y + x } ) :: Int -> IO ()

main'''' (y :: Int) = do
   x <- readLn :: IO Int
   print $ y + x :: IO ()
```

Apparently, it was just not envisioned that signatures in patterns might be useful. But they sure are, so `ScopedTypeVariables` introduced that possibility.

Comment: Is this the `Expression Type-Signatures` http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.16 ?